# In Rails fixtures, who is Quentin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

In acts-as-authenticated, and now restful-authentication, the first user fixture is "Quentin."

Just curious if anyone knows the origin of that name? Quentin Tarantino? Someone's dog or child?

Comment: May be it IS Quentin Tarantino! :) I'm waiting for someone to answer this..

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from Rick Olson = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Quire